# Python Program is not remembering a variable

Tags: python

I'm making a program where a user can upload a .csv file, then the contents will be displayed, then the file will be manipulated, then the manipulated file will be sent as an attachment to an email.

My problem is, python is not recalling the 'fname' in the SortingCSV and UploadAction functions. So I can't do anything with the displayed .csv file content.

Here's the error I get:

> NameError: name 'fname' is not defined

```
def load_file(self):
#Upload a CSV file and display its contents
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),
                                       ("HTML files", "*.html;*.htm"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
    print(fname)
    print('The file has been uploaded, contents are displayed below')

    import csv

    with open(fname) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(" ".join(row))

def SortingCSV(self):
#Allows user to switch the contents of the file to the desired ings
    print(fname)
    print("Tkinter is easy to use!")

def UploadAction(self):
#Allows user to send the converted file to website

    import smtplib

    content = 'Here is your completed file'
    attach = (fname.csv)
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('[insert email]','[insert password]')

mail.sendmail('[insert email]','[insert recipient]',content)

    mail.close()    
    print("The file has been sent to your inbox")        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Comment: Should be `self.fname` for Python to "remember".

Comment: There's no such thing as "not remember".... if python can't find a name, either you're out of the scope it was defined or it was not defined at all.

Comment: Yes it is out of scope. Because you have defined variable fname in load_file() and once that function has been called and exited, other functions might not know about fname() because of scope.

Comment: You have some indentation issues, too.

Answer (score 2):

Add `global fname` as the first line to all functions that use the variable. This will make `fname` a globally visible variable. Global variables are evil, though. A better solution is to pack all your GUI functions into a class.

Comment: Looking at the code, I'm guessing that the posted material is actually part of a class called MyFrame.

Comment: Thank you! The program now recognizes the file. But I'm still having trouble getting my desired results. When I add the attachment in it causes this error: smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (555, b'5.5.2 Syntax error. c186sm9771727qke.33 - gsmtp', '[insert email]')

Comment: Of course - you did not insert email. You also did not insert the password and the recipient, but it's a whole different error.

Comment: I actually did, I just didn't want to post the info publically

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing here with something called variable "scope".

To you, the script is one continuous list of instructions.  But to Python it's three mini-scripts, each one starting with a `def` statement and ending when the indentation goes back to the original level.  What happens inside those def statement blocks (which are called functions or methods, depending on whether they're inside a `class` block or not and which isn't clear from the excerpt of your code) have no effect on the other sections of code.

Therefore, even though you define `fname` up near the top of the code, it only exists inside the `load_file()` function.

Assuming that this code really is nested inside a `class` (I think that might be the case because of the references to `self`) if you were to assign the filename to `self.fname` that would make `fname` an *instance* variable, available from any `def` block (method) of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is scoped to the method in which it is declared, here load_file(). If you want to use it outside of the method, declare it as a class attribute `self.fname`. You then use it inside your class with `self.fname`.

Edit: I'm assuming your function are class methods, since you use `self` as argument.